# How to change deprecated onPrepareOptionsMenu

Tags: java, android, menu, android-inflate

I tried to change code for deprecated menu methods such as setHasOptionsMenu, onPrepareOptionsMenu... used in fragment.
I found maybe similar task [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71917856/sethasoptionsmenuboolean-unit-is-deprecated-deprecated-in-java), but I don't know how to change.

Here is current code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true); //<--deprecated
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  //<--deprecated
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
    if(item != null)
        item.setVisible(false);
}
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'am not sure if I understand changes of Android SDK. Do I have to remove onCreateOptionsMenu from Activity and put addMenuProvider to every fragment with onPrepareMenu?
I have only one menu.xml and I want to hide some item in some fragment.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77485240/8051287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am not sure, if it is ok, but this modification working.
In activity I left menu methods:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

In a fragments I put these:

```
requireActivity().addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareMenu(@NonNull Menu menu) {
            MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete_tags);
            if(item != null)
                item.setVisible(false);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            //...

            return false;
        }
    }, getViewLifecycleOwner(), Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
```

It seems to work. It was necessary drop inflate from onCreateMenu and add onPrepareMenu.